# Can acne bacteria become resistant to Clindamycin?

Tags: antibiotics, acne, resistance

Clindamycinum is an antibiotic used to treat skin and vaginal infections. Can people use Clindamycinum for more than 60 days or will the bacteria become resistant to it?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE, Asogi! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Personalised medical advice is off-topic here. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: I edited your question to deal with the issue @LangLangC pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you disbelieve the instructions?

> However, with erythromycin, clindamycin, and tetracyclines, the rate of resistance is associated with point mutations in rRNA (Ross et al., 2001). Mutations in the 23SrRNA component of an E. coli equivalent nucleotide bases give varying degrees of resistance to erythromycin and clindamycin.

So, given prolonged use Propionibacterium acnes in Acne Vulgaris will become resistant to clindamycin. There will be a selection pressure for bacteria that develop the mutation.

https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/460620_2